# Passing arguments to drupal_get_form()

Tags: 7, forms

How can I pass arguments to `drupal_get_form()` in Drupal 7?

```
function new_menu_callback() {
  $vars = some_example_function(); // returns: array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two');
  $output = $vars[2];
  $output .= drupal_render(drupal_get_form('new_form'));
}

function new_form($form, &$form_state) {
  // How can I access $vars[1] from new_menu_callback() here?
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of examples for this. Run a grep for drupal_get_form from drupal root directory.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just add `$vars` as second argument.

```
drupal_get_form('new_form', $vars);
```

and...

```
function new_form($form, &$form_state, $vars) {
// ...
```

Quote from [drupal_get_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7)

> ... Any additional arguments are passed on to the functions called by drupal_get_form(), including the unique form constructor function. For example, the node_edit form requires that a node object is passed in here when it is called. These are available to implementations of hook_form_alter() and hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() as the array $form_state['build_info']['args'].

Answer (score 3):

The additional arguments you pass to [`drupal_get_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) are available in `$form_state['build_info']['args']`, but you can't have function calls in your `page arguments`. I'd suggest the following approach:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['mymodule/example'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('mymodule_form'),
    );
    return $items;
}


function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state) {
  // this function now uses dev/user friendly named keys
  $vars = mymodule_example_function();
  $form = array();

  $form['heading'] = array(
    '#markup' => check_plain($vars['heading']),
  );

  // use other arguments here

  return $form;
}
```

The rest of what you need is in the [Form API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7)

Comment: This function should be used instead of drupal_build_form() when $form_state is not needed (i.e., when initially rendering the form) and is often used as a menu callback.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it was solved with a mix of @kalabro's answer and my own way to deal with it.

So basically I have a static landingpage where I use tokens. In the `hook_tokens` I call the register form via `$form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form', 'register-test');`.

And finally in the hook_form_alter I check the if the String is "register-test". This is done via `$form_state['build_info']['args'][0]`. Here the function:

```
function hook_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
...
if ($form_state['build_info']['args'][0] == 'register-test') {
    // manipulate the form as usual
    $form['...
  }
...
}
```